# Windows 8.1 / iSCSI / Hyper-V Depedencies

Tags: hyper-v, iscsi, windows-8.1

My workstation has Windows 8.1 and uses iSCSI for SAN storage, which is where the Hyper-V configuration and VHD files sit. When the workstation is booting up, the VM is not able to auto start because "`The Virtual Machines configuration 037C33D6-433C-42AF-B51A-F7292A1FB2A4 at 'H:\Degas\vnix' is no longer accessible: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x80070003).`" What dependencies do I need to configure to tell Hyper-V to wait until iSCSI is up and running before it starts looking for files on the SAN?

Comment: I would say none, the way your iscsi is configured looks wrong. As in: It is a standard setup to have vms on an ISCSI target.

Comment: I would agree, but possibly since this is not a server operating system, it doesn't put that much priority on iSCSI?

Comment: Posibly, but then seriously - no clue. This is why I just commented. Not using Hyper-V on a workstation here (although I really look forward to the time I have to, it is a great tool for developers FINALLY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Microsoft support article has the answer. You need to set the Hyper-V services to depend upon the iSCSI services if they are not already.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888

You should also make sure that your iSCSI services are not set to use Automatic (Delayed startup) as discussed at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015189/automatic-vs-automatic-delayed-start

But like TomTom said, it sounds like you have not properly configured iSCSI and I would recommend redoing the steps required to configure your iSCSI initiator to work with your iSCSI target before attempting the steps above, because while these steps may offer a workaround to the problem you're experiencing they are not a replacement for having it properly configured from jump street.

Comment: I already had Hyper-V setup to depend on iSCSI. Hyper-V showed errors because it could not access the configuration files, which were on the SAN. I changed Hyper-V to start on "Delayed startup" and that works. Not ideal, but as long as I don't need to manually start the VM's, I am happy.

I didn't have this issue when I was running just Windows 8...